# BeagleBone Black Rev. C Android 4.2.2 Serial Access

Tags: android, serial-port, root, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I have a BeagleBone Black Rev.C running Texas Instrument's stock Android 4.2.2 image off the microSD card.

I attempted to use the SerialPort_1.1.apk application (found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/downloads/list)) but when I try to access "Console", "Loopback", or "Send 01010101" I get "Error: You do not have read/write permission to the serial port."

I tried following the directions here:
http://beaglebone.cameon.net/home/serial-ports-uart

and here:
[Root permission to configure UART1 in Beaglebone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683336/root-permission-to-configure-uart1-in-beaglebone)

but neither of these did anything. I feel like I probably need root on this system, which doesn't seem to be the case...

My question is, does anyone know how to get root on the Android 4.2.2 image on BeagleBone OR does anyone know a specific workaround for this? Being able to access the Serial pins directly on the BeagleBone rather than going through virtual USB would save my company considerable dollars.

Comment: Do you have serial device nodes? What are their group ownership and permissions? Is your apk in a corresponding group?

Comment: What do you mean by device nodes? I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: You may want to start by reading up on serial communications in situations where the bone is running a traditional, non-Andriod linux, and then comparing that to the situation on your Androidized linux.